# entering a text from a text file before the first line of another file using sed

Tags: sed

I have a text file named: "header" and I wish to insert it as the header of "anotherfile" which already contains some text. 
The final output should be:

"header" text content 
 right above
"otherfile" text content

On ubuntu linux system I tried the following, which got me close but not quite:

```
cat otherfile | sed '1 r header' - > myoutputfile
```

the problem with this solution is that it enters all the content of "header" one line AFTER the first line of "otherfile", instead of BEFORE the first line of "otherfile".

Is there any neat way to make the content of my "header" file appear as the header of "otherfile" ?

i should mention that the following attempt

```
cat otherfile | sed '0 r header' - > myoutputfile
```

fails with the following error message: 
**sed: -e expression #1, char 3: invalid usage of line address 0**

Comment: What keeps you from using `cat header otherfile > myoutputfile`?

Comment: if there is a while lot of pipe'ing happening with "otherfile" before coming to add the header and you don't want to break your pipe into two commands - so you better use the 'sed' solution. otherwise sure, you can output to a temp output file and use: cat header tempoutput > myoutputfile ; rm tempoutput;    but this is not as neat as the solution i wrote.

Comment: Then the problem should state that, because as it is written, there is no reason to use sed.

Comment: Problem asked specifically how-to with sed. Preceding [cat otherfile] which "isn't necessary" either hints of a pipe. For ex.: 
my_saf_file=`ls *.saf`; samtools view -SH $my_saf_file -o header;cat $my_saf_file |sed -e '/\trDNA\t/d' -e '/\tSN:rDNA\t/d' -e '/\tmtDNA\t/d' -e '/\tSN:mtDNA\t/d'|samtools view -Sb -|intersectBed -v -abam stdin -b /data/leelab/common/Mus_musculus/UCSC/mm9/GenomeStudio/Mus_musculus/mm9_rRNA_tRNA_chrM_mask.gtf | samtools view -h - |grep -v '^\@' | sed -e '2{x;G};1{h;rheader' -e 'd}' - > ${my_saf_file%.*}.cleaned3.saf

Comment: Glad it worked for you, but I still think the question could be more clear, see also the comment left on your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the question stated in your question is simply:

```
cat header otherfile > myoutputfile
```

But to answer the question in your comments: Assuming that `cat otherfile` is some pipeline, not actually a file, all you need is:

```
cat otherfile | cat header - > myoutputfile
```

e.g.:

```
$ cat file1
a
b
c

$ cat file2
foo
bar

$ cat file1 | cat file2 -
foo
bar
a
b
c
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '1h;1r header' -e '1d;2H;2g' file
```

or:

```
sed '1e cat header' file
```

Answer (score -1):

ok, this is the solution that works for me:

```
cat otherfile | sed -e '2{x;G};1{h;rheader' -e 'd}' - > myoutputfile
```

Comment: That makes no sense. I was about to start with UUOC but it's actually UUOS, Useless Use Of Sed, as it's exactly the job `cat` was created to do: `cat rheader otherfile > myoutputfile`.

Comment: @EdMorton See comments under the question: apparently it's part of a super long processing chain.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Even if `cat otherfile` is a chain of piped commands this is a very complicated way to prepend the contents of another file vs, say, `cat otherfile | cat header - > myoutputfile`.

Comment: @EdMorton Now *that* is the proper solution.